# Hide keyboard on mobile while on focus of autocomplete box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, material-ui, autocomplete

I want keyboard to stay hidden on focus (or on click) of autocomplete box and appear(keyboard) only while I start typing.

Below code hides keyboard on keypress of any alphabets and numbers. But I want keyboard to be hidden initially on focus and appear while I start typing. Thank you

```
 <Autocomplete                                             
             value={this.state.result}
             options={this.state.Data}
             autoHighlight={true}
             renderOption={(option) => (
                   <Typography class="typography">{option}</Typography>
             )}
            getOptionLabel={option => option}
            onChange={this.onChangeCapturedData}
                                       
            // below hides keyboard on typing, but I want keyboard to hide on focus and appear on typing
            onKeyPress={(event) => {
                    if (event.keyCode = 'enter') {
                       event.target.blur();
                       console.log("enter")
                    }                                                
           }}      
                                                                              
           renderInput={params => (
                 <TextField {...params} label="Data" variant={"outlined"}
                 size="small" InputLabelProps={{ style: { fontSize: 14, color: '#33333C', fontFamily: "Arial" }, shrink: true }} fullWidth />
          )}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the onKeyPress method to the TextField input component as a method to onChange and use `touch` as the value for `blurOnSelect` prop of the Autocomplete field

Comment: Thank you, I have added code for reference. You mean I should be adding blur to Textfield of autocomplete component?

Comment: Let me update my answer